# Using request objects for non-body parameters in Minimal API

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-web-api, minimal-apis

Is it possible to have a request class where it is possible to declare the minimal API request parameters in .NET 6? I know that a similar feature will be provided by .NET 7.

What I am trying to achieve is the following:

```
public class GetProductByIdRequestDto
{
    [FromRoute(Name = "id")] public string Id { get; set; } 
}

app.MapGet("/products/{id}", GetProductByIdRequestDto request => HandleRequest(request));
```

The problem is that:

- If I don't declare any attribute AspNet automatically inferres that it should be from body and this causes an error since it's a GET request
- If I use the [FromRoute] in the MapGet delegate AspNet throws an error because there is no route parameter named "request"

I know that

```
app.MapGet("/products/{id}", [FromRoute(Name = "id")]string productId => HandleRequest(productId));
```

would work, but this is not what I'm looking for

Comment: Did you try `app.MapGet("/products/{id}", ([FromRoute] GetProductByIdRequestDto request) => HandleRequest(request));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK there are no out of the box option for it. You can leverage custom parameter binding via [`TryParse` or `BindAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/minimal-apis?view=aspnetcore-6.0#custom-binding):

```cs
public class GetProductByIdRequestDto
{
    public string Id { get; set; }

    public static ValueTask<GetProductByIdRequestDto?> BindAsync(HttpContext context,
        ParameterInfo parameter)
    {
        const string idKey = "id";

        var result = new GetProductByIdRequestDto
        {
            Id = context.Request.RouteValues[idKey]?.ToString()
        };

        return ValueTask.FromResult<GetProductByIdRequestDto?>(result);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

This is supported in .NET 7 via the new `[AsParameters]` attribute:

```
public class GetProductByIdRequestDto
{
    [FromRoute(Name = "id")] public string Id { get; set; } 
}

app.MapGet("/products/{id}", [AsParameters] GetProductByIdRequestDto request => HandleRequest(request));
```

This will flatten the properties of `GetProductByIdRequestDto` and treat them as if they were top level arguments defined in the lambda itself.